# Templating with Meteor and Angular

Tags: angularjs, meteor

When using **angular** package i can't use  the **templating** package. Otherwise I get this error:

```
 While determining active plugins:
 error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates
 and templating) are both trying to handle *.html

 While determining active plugins:
 error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates
 and templating) are both trying to handle *.html

 While determining active plugins:
 error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates
 and templating) are both trying to handle *.html
```

Without templating I can't use the basic Template formality:

```
Template.layout.onCreated(function () {

});
```

Since I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
```

How to use **templating and angular** in a meteor app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Blaze templates while using angular-meteor package.

check this link for details:
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/bootstrapping

You have to remove blaze templates(default UI package for Meteor) with the below command:

```
$ meteor remove blaze-html-templates
```